# Git branch for dist/production

Tags: git, gitlab, git-branch

i have a project in existing repository, the folder structure :

```
myproject (master)
+-- app/
+-- dist/ (.gitignore in master, but i want it as production branch, is it possible?)
```

is it called sub-repo or whatever?
how to setup my local git to remote branches?

Answer (score 0):

By default, branches in Git have nothing to do with each other. However, when you tell a local branch to "track" a remote branch, you create a connection between these two branches. Your local branch now has a "counterpart" on the remote server.

Nice example you can find here: https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/track-remote-upstream-branch